# std::regex::multiline does not exist

Tags: c++, regex-lookarounds

I try to use multiline regex syntax, so that `^$` match beginning and end of line in C++. Since C++17, `std::regex` and `std::regex_constants` should contain a flag `multiline` that turns this on ([see the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type)).

I've tried this on Apple Clang, GCC on Ubuntu and Alpine. In none of those it works, the symbol is said to be missing. What am I doing wrong? Did I misunderstand this is in the standard since C++17?

```cpp
#include <regex>
int main() {
  auto flag = std::regex::multiline;
}
```

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008
$ g++ regex.cpp -std=c++17 -o regex
regex.cpp: In function 'int main()':
regex.cpp:3:27: error: 'multiline' is not a member of 'std::__cxx11::regex' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_regex<char>'}
    3 |   auto flag = std::regex::multiline;
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type::multiline`? `std::regex_constants::multiline`?

Comment: `std::regex::multiline` *should* work, as the flag constants are *supposed to be* declared in the `std::basic_regex` class as well.  So this is likely a bug in your compiler's implementation.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I tried both, same result.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I tried GCC9 and (Apple)Clang, neither of which work.

Comment: @ephimetheus Then obviously those *implementations* have not caught up to what the *standard* says should be implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About 2.5 years later, `std::regex::multiline` is indeed present in GCC12 and up and Clang 15 and up: https://godbolt.org/z/bocnr9Yab

Answer (score 1):

It's a big limitation of `std::regex`. The only good solution I found was to use `boost::regex` instead, and then you can do multilines just fine, and the nice thing is that it's exactly the same syntax, you just need to replace all your `std::` with `boost::`. Oh, and it also runs about 20x faster.

Have a look at the comparison table here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/boost.html

Comment: Saying to use a different library doesn't answer the question at all. The issue here, from 2 years ago, is that it's an old compiler that didn't have it implemented yet.

Comment: And it's still not implemented, even today. So it's very relevant. There is no way to make it work with std::regex.

Comment: It is supported by g++, which OP was using.

Comment: I can confirm that `std::regex::multiline` exists in gcc12 now, but still seems to be absent in clang14.

Comment: @paulgessinger No it is present in clang14, and even clang13 (but you need to use the c++17 standard).

Comment: @Michael: https://godbolt.org/z/bocnr9Yab <- it's indeed in clang15 now if you add -std=c++17, but it's not there in clang13 and clang14.

Comment: @paulgessinger Seems weird, but that has to be wrong. I literally just checked on a FreeBSD with Clang 13, and a Fedora 36 with Clang 14. I've recently had to fix building issues with some compilers, and I was pretty sure I hadn't had the multiline problem with those compilers... just confirmed it again. It works.

Comment: @Michael hm, which stdlib are you using in fedora? Many distributions default to stdlibc++, which might be gcc12+ for you and already have it. 

The godbolts should use the respective libc++ version matching the clang/llvm version.

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into this too, still using clang-14 + gcc-11 at my box, and found this workaround:

the `^` is almost* replaceable by `(?:^|\n)` and `$` similarly by `(?:$|\n)` (with caveat of consuming the `\n` char).

*) if for example the `$` replacement does match at end of line, the `^` replacement will not match at next line because the `\n` is already gone. Thus in the example below I did split the two rules into two individual regex rules and search for them individually.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

//multi-line input string
const std::string t = "abc1 xyz2 abc3\nxyz4 abc5 xyz6\nabc7 xyz8 xyz9";
// search "^abc#" and "xyz#$" over multiple lines of input
// `^` is replaced with non-capture group `(?:^|\n)`, `$` with `(?:$|\n)`:
const auto e_bol = std::regex(R"((?:^|\n)(abc\d))");
const auto e_eol = std::regex(R"((xyz\d)(?:$|\n))");

int main() {
    std::cout << "input:\n" << t << std::endl;
    auto it_e = std::sregex_iterator();
    auto it_bol = std::sregex_iterator(t.cbegin(), t.cend(), e_bol);
    auto it_eol = std::sregex_iterator(t.cbegin(), t.cend(), e_eol);
    std::cout << "\n\"^abc\\d\" search:";
    for (;it_bol != it_e; ++it_bol) std::cout << ' ' << it_bol->str(1);
    std::cout << "\n\"xyz\\d$\" search:";
    for (;it_eol != it_e; ++it_eol) std::cout << ' ' << it_eol->str(1);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
input:
abc1 xyz2 abc3
xyz4 abc5 xyz6
abc7 xyz8 xyz9

"^abc\d" search: abc1 abc7
"xyz\d$" search: xyz6 xyz9
```